# Glassfish 3 + ear + logback.xml

Tags: jsf, glassfish, ear, logback

I'm using logback in an EAR-File which contains a JAR (ejb) and a WAR. This should run on a Glassfish v3 Server. Everything works, except the loading of the logback.xml. This can't be found. 
I build the Project with Netbeans. The used external libs are in the lib-Directory of the EAR (Which shouldn't make a difference where they are...). I've planed to put the logback.xml-File in the root-Directory or another Subdirectory in the EAR. The Classpath is set in the Manifest-Files of the JAR and WAR. But for some Reasons the logback.xml wasn't found... (The build ear contains the logback.xml ;) )

I've tryied every location of the logback.xml. Even in the WAR or JAR. Nothing worked...

If I use a standalone WAR then everything works fine and the logback.xml was found. (OK. Not everything. Changing the Classpath in the Manifest doesn't work...)

So my Question: Has anybody already get logback.xml to run within an EAR?

Here is my Manifest (I hope, that this ist the correct Syntax):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2 
Created-By: 1.7.0_147-icedtea-b147 (Oracle Corporation) 
Class-Path: ./
```

Hope someone can help me.

Regards

Comment: Note: you May want to use Glassfish own logging.  Then you need the JDK14 slf4j module instead of logback.  This is what we use

Comment: I use logback with slf4j as backend.

Comment: Also note that you can attach a listener to logback so you can see where it looks for the configuration files.  This might help you.

Comment: This is a good hint. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem creating a separated simple jar that I deploy exploded inside the EAR (using Maven and a separated module config.jar).
In practice, the logback.xml was inserted in lib/config.jar/logback.xml

Comment: So you essentially put a new jar in the classpath common to all deployments.  This is in my experience the only way to see things across deployed artifacts.  Note, that the application server cannot help you centralizing logs if you need to be clustered.

Answer (score 2):

I've found out a solution without putting another jar in the classpath.
1) Just put the logback.xml into the classpath of the war application (/src/java/ for instance);
2) Use a ServletContextListener to load the file using getResourceAsStream and, eventually, set some parameters (like the application name) as in the snipped below:

```
@Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Logback contextInitialized !!!!");
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(); 
        JoranConfigurator jc = new JoranConfigurator(); 
        jc.setContext(context); context.reset(); 
        // override default configuration 
        // inject the name of the current application as "application-name" 
        // property of the LoggerContext 
        context.putProperty("application-name", "menu_dinamico"); 
        try { 
            InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logback.xml");
            if(is == null) {
                System.out.println("Logback xml file non trovato");
            }
            else {
                jc.doConfigure(is);
            }
        } catch (JoranException ex) {
            System.out.println("Logback contextInitialized error");
            StatusPrinter.print(context);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now the file logback.xml is recognized.

Comment: Hi Maxqua72, I followed your advise and did the same thing on an EAR level logback configuration. Trying to manipulate my class path entries or change the ear structure was far more complex in terms of side effects!!

Comment: This solution worked, but be aware that the configuration will be loaded after the startup. so if you have any other class that is being configured before startup (e.g., JPA, Quartz, Spring, ...) they will log to debug in the console until the deploy has completed. In the end I went for the accepted answer solution.