# Executable jar not able to find logback.xml file

Tags: logging, logback

I have standalone application which is bundled in executable `jar`. In MANIFEST file of executable `jar`, there is an entry for class-path where all dependent `jar` is listed (including all logback implementation jars ). This executable jar also contains `logback.xml` file.

With this structure, when I run my application with simple `java -jar MyApplication.jar` command, application runs fine with proper logging. But here main problem is, to change log level, one need to open jar file and I can't ask client to do that. So I placed `logback.xml` outside of jar but now all logging is happening on console.

I referred [Logback can't find logback.xml even though it exists (on the classpath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440881/logback-cant-find-logback-xml-even-though-it-exists-on-the-classpath) and there solution mentioned is to bundle logback.xml inside a separate jar. But this solution is bad. That way client can't change log level easily. How to make it work with logback.xml outside of jar.

I tried adding `logback.xml` in MANIFEST Class-Path entry along with entry for other dependent jar, but didn't work. My application structure is like below

> +RootFolder
> --MyApplication.jar
> --logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
> --logback-core-1.1.3.jar
> --slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
> --Other-Dependency.jar
> **--logback.xml**

Anyone has already solve this problem? I don't want to use programmatic configuration with Configurator.  Currently workaround is to use option `-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml` But how to make it work with out ?

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080736/logback-configuration-issue-cannot-find-logback-xml?rq=1)  where someone was facing some different issue but for him it was working fine when added . (dot) in Class-Path entry of MANIFEST.  I applied same solution. So instead of having logback.xml file as part of Class-Path I simply put . and it worked.